# Use a package's older version in R

Tags: r, version-control, package, version, survey

Between me and a colleague, we've got some small differences in results using the `survey` package. All things being equal, we saw that I was using the package's latest version (3.36), while my coworker used version 3.33-2. 
He already replicated his results with the package's latest version, getting no differences. Now we need to replicate my results with his package version (we are looking to control all possible error sources). How can I go back to his version to replicate his results? I know the package's source url is https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/, but it offers only the latest version.

TL;DR: How to install and use an R's package older version? Is the method different according to different packages?

Thanks

Comment: There are [older sources on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/survey/) or check the CRAN read-only github repo of the package? Just wget/curl/tar/ whatever tool you'd prefer and build?

Comment: You can use the microsoft repo and package `checkpoint` to accomplish this. This package is pretty useful for reproducible research.